# Is Azure Active Directory extension property searchable

Tags: azure-active-directory

user story: a anonymous user should be able to create survey, paste in survey participants' email from their outlook, these participants will become valid user in AD, with their emails as primary search key as extension property in AD. User will get mail, being notified that a survey is ready for them......etc.

1. Since Azure Email property is only readable, I can only add the user mail as an extension property. When extension property such as "SkeypID", "Email" is added, the searchability is also available?

ex. DirectoryService.users.Where(it => it.myproperty!= null && it.myproperty.Equals('test@gmail.com')).SingleOrDefault();

1. Let's assume that I want to give access to anonymous user creating user in Active directory, (Sorry, did not try this one myself before asking), does it work without using a user identity as company administrator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, extension attributes are searchable. Use a query like the one referenced at the [GitHub README](https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebApp-GraphAPI-OrgChart-DotNet) for my OrgChart extensions sample application. The link should look something like this:
   GET https://graph.windows.net/contoso.com/users/joe@contoso.com?api-version=1.21-preview&$filter=extension_d8dde29f1095422e91537a6cb22a2f74_skypeId+eq+'joe.smith'
2. To allow an anonymous user to create a user in ActiveDirectory you could create an application with write permissions to your directory and have that application allow anonymous access. My OrgChart extensions sample application allows you to create and delete users, but you need to provide it application credentials and a tenant where that app has write consent.